# What does rdstate() return value mean?

Tags: c++, io, eof

```
istream& Read(istream &is)
{
    std::string buf;
    while (is >> buf)       
    {   
        cout << is.eofbit << " " << is.failbit << " " << is.badbit << endl;
        cout << is.rdstate() << endl;
        cout << buf << endl;
    }
    cout << is.eofbit << " " << is.failbit << " " << is.badbit << endl;
    cout << is.rdstate() << endl;
    is.clear();
    cout << is.eofbit << " " << is.failbit << " " << is.badbit << endl;
    cout << is.rdstate() << endl;
    return is;
}
```

If I input normal characters like "test",the output is `1 2 4 0`.
Then I type CTRL+Z (windows),the output is `1 2 4 3` `1 2 4 0`.

Question :
1. what does `rdstate()` return value means? (Why does it output 3,not 2? not 1?)

2. Why did not `is.eofbit`and `is.failbit` change after I typed CTRL+Z ?  (As *C++ Primer 5th Editon* says,Reaching end-of-file sets both eofbit and failbit )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The member `std::ios::rdstate()` simply returns a combination of the state flags `std::ios_base::badbit`, `std::ios_base::eofbit`, and `std::ios_base::failbit`. Under which conditions which bits gets set isn't entirely consistent but the intent is the following:

1. `std::ios_base::badbit` gets set when the stream is in genuinely dysfunctional state and you [probably] won't get anything out of it. For example, this flag is set if there is no stream buffer or when any of the operations on the stream has thrown an exception.
2. `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set when an input operation failed, e.g., because a formatted input operation got an unexpected characters. It may be possible to recover from this error by clearing it, ignoring a few characters, and trying again.
3. `std::ios_base::eofbit` gets set when [the current] EOF is reached, i.e., when there could be no more characters extracted for now.

Now, in your case you entered a string and reading it was successful, i.e., there are no flags set. Note that reading stopped with the newline character, i.e., you really entered `"test\n"` and the stream extracted these five characters. When you then ended the stream, the stream reached EOF while trying to read a string, i.e., it set `std::ios_base::eofbit` *and* the input failed also setting `std::ios_base::failbit`.

If you want to see only `std::ios_base::eofbit` set, you can do so by using a stream which ends with a word right at the end of the stream without any following space character. An easy way to get such a stream is to use an `std::istringstream` and read from that:

```
std::istringstream in("test");
Read(in);
```

Another easy set up is to see `std::ios_base::badbit` set: you'd just create a stream without a stream buffer, e.g.:

```
std::istream in(0);
Read(in);
```

Note that the stream will initially have `std::ios_base::badbit` set and also get `std::ios_base::failbit` set upon an attempt to read a character. After `clear()`ing the `std::ios_base::badbit` will still be set, though.

To get `std::ios_base::failbit` set without also having `std::ios_base::eofbit` set you'll need to prevent it from seeing a non-whitespace character: the input operator for `std::string` by default start off skipping whitespace and then reads until it either reaches whitespace or EOF and it is successful if it could read at least one non-whitespace character. An approach to do that is to turn automatic skipping of whitespace off, e.g.:

```
std::istringstream in("test test");
Read(in >> std::noskipws);
```

BTW, note that there is no guarantee for the values of `std::ios_base::eofbit`, `std::ios_base::failbit`, or `std::ios_base::badbit` other than they can be used as bitmasks in some form.

Comment: I know that std::ios::rdstate() simply returns a combination of the state flags . But I don't understand what its output means . e.g.:   If I try this:`std::istream in(0);  Read(in);`,the output of `cout << is.rdstate() << endl;` is 3 . Does it means that changes three flags(see 3 as decimal ) or changes two flags(see 3 as binary (11))?  (ps. My English is poor ,can you understand what I want to say?)

Answer (score 2):

The member `std::ios::rdstate()` simply returns a combination of the state flags `std::ios_base::badbit`, `std::ios_base::eofbit`, and `std::ios_base::failbit`.But the size of each state flag is not 1 bit, the type of all three state flags are  `enum std::_Iosb<int>::_Iostate`, which is machine-dependent integral as well as `std::strm::iostate`. On my machine, they account for 4 bytes.

> But I don't understand what its output means

when only `badbit` gets set explicity or directly, the value of `s.rdstate()`is 4.
when only `failbit` gets set explicity or directly, the value of `s.rdstate()` is 2.
when only `eofbit` gets set explicity or directly, the value of `s.rdstate()` is 1.

when several parts of them get set explicity or directly, the value of `s.rdstate()` can calculated from the sum of the corresponding value, namely, the 1st bit of `s.rdstate()`indicates the state of`eofbit`,the 2nd bit of `s.rdstate()`indicates the state of`failbit`,the 3th bit of `s.rdstate()`indicates the state of`badbit`.

But the interesting thing is when the `badbit` gets set explicitly or directly, the `failbit` will get set in response(not explicity or directly).At this time, the value of `s.rdstate()` do not count `failbit` in. Read my code and see the output, you will understand what I mean.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<istream>

std::istream & print(std::istream &is) {
    static unsigned cnt = 0;
    ++cnt;
    std::cout << cnt << ((cnt % 10 == 1) ? "st" :
        (cnt % 10 == 2) ? "nd" : "th")
        << " call print" << "\n";

    std::cout<< "is.badbit: " << is.badbit << "\n"
        << "is.failbit: " << is.failbit << "\n"
        << "is.eofbit: " << is.eofbit << "\n"
        << "is.bad(): " << is.bad() << "\n" 
        << "is.fail(): " << is.fail() << "\n"
        << "is.eof(): " << is.eof() << "\n"
        << "is.rdstate(): " << is.rdstate() << "\n";
    return is;
}

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof(iostate): " <<sizeof(std::istream::iostate)<<"\n";
    cout << "sizeof(goodbit): " << sizeof(std::istream::goodbit) << "\n";
    cout << typeid(std::istream::goodbit).name();
    cout << endl;

    print(cin);
    cout << endl;

    cin.setstate(std::istream:: badbit);
    print(cin);
    cout << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.setstate(std::istream::failbit);
    print(cin);
    cout << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.setstate(std::istream::eofbit);
    print(cin);
    cout << endl;


    cin.clear();
    cin.setstate(std::istream::badbit);
    cin.setstate(std::istream::failbit);
    print(cin);
    cout << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.setstate(std::istream::badbit);
    cin.setstate(std::istream::eofbit);
    print(cin);
    cout << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.setstate(std::istream::failbit);
    cin.setstate(std::istream::eofbit);
    print(cin);
    cout << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
sizeof(iostate): 4
sizeof(goodbit): 4

1st call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 0
is.fail(): 0
is.eof(): 0
is.rdstate(): 0

2nd call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 1
is.fail(): 1
is.eof(): 0
is.rdstate(): 4

3th call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 0
is.fail(): 1
is.eof(): 0
is.rdstate(): 2

4th call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 0
is.fail(): 0
is.eof(): 1
is.rdstate(): 1

5th call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 1
is.fail(): 1
is.eof(): 0
is.rdstate(): 6

6th call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 1
is.fail(): 1
is.eof(): 1
is.rdstate(): 5

7th call print
is.badbit: 4
is.failbit: 2
is.eofbit: 1
is.bad(): 0
is.fail(): 1
is.eof(): 1
is.rdstate(): 3
```