# ifstream checking read error

Tags: c++11, ifstream

I found the following code for reading whole file into a string. Unfortunately, I do no know how to properly check if whole file content has been loaded. There is is_open function, however it does not provide all information. Will be grateful for any help!

```
std::ifstream file(fileName);
std::string content = std::string((
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) utilities to examine (and reset if needed) the state of the input file stream.

In your program this would for instance work as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("sample.txt");
    std::string content = std::string((
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    std::cout << "Reading status: " << file.rdstate() << std::endl;

    if (file.rdstate())
        std::cout << "Reading the file failed" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first output is for demonstration - `file.rdstate` will be 0 if everything went well. If something went wrong it's value will be a system dependent sum of the three flags that contributes to it. I recommend you read the cited reference.

The `if` statement is the actual check that you can use in your program. You can add an exception throw in there too, or even replace the if with an [assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) - both strategies in case you actually want the program to stop if reading file failed. When using assert you would replace the if with

```
assert(!file.rdstate());
```

and add the `<cassert>` header. Assert will throw and terminate your program if the `file.rdstate()` value is 0 (interpreted as `false`), since you want the opposite - there is a negation upfront.

You can easily test these concepts/idea simply by specifying a non-existent file name, but I also recommend you [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058822/2763915) for more explanation and testing ideas that will clarify the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the End Of File, or EOF flag.

[End of file fliag](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/)